# Postgres ignoring wal_level setting in conf

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I am trying to configure replication in Postgres, and running into an issue where the server is ignoring the setting for `wal_level` in the configuration file.

I have set in the config file:

```
wal_level = hot_standby
max_wal_senders = 5
```

However when I went to start Postgres I ran into the error:

> WAL streaming (max_wal_senders > 0) requires wal_level "archive", "hot_standby", or "logical"

If I set `max_wal_senders = 0`, the server starts fine, but running "show all" in psql shows that `wal_level = minimal`.

```
 -bash-4.2$ grep wal_level postgresql.conf
wal_level = hot_standby                 # minimal, archive, hot_standby, or logical

-bash-4.2$ psql -c 'show "wal_level";'
 wal_level
-----------
 minimal
```

Any idea why it would be ignoring the configuration value?

Nothing of note in the Postgres error log:

```
Oct 13 11:03:53 postgres[12324]: [3-1] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2016-10-13 10:55:35 UTC
Oct 13 11:03:53 postgres[12324]: [4-1] LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
Oct 13 11:03:53 postgres[12328]: [3-1] LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
Oct 13 11:03:53 postgres[12321]: [3-1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Just the one `wal_level` config line and `archive_mode` is enabled and configured to rsync archive files to the slave. I've uploaded the config here: http://pastebin.com/Vi3vByc1

I've checked and it's definitely loading the correct config file.

```
-bash-4.2$ psql -c 'show config_file;'
             config_file
--------------------------------------
 /data/pgsql/9.5/data/postgresql.conf
(1 row)

-bash-4.2$ grep wal_level /data/pgsql/9.5/data/postgresql.conf
wal_level = hot_standby                 # minimal, archive, hot_standby, or logical
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at the postgresql.auto.conf file - it's populated if you changed it using `alter system`. 
Also, make sure to restart the instance and not just reload it as this kind of change requires restart.

Comment: Eventually found it in there alright, although I don't remember ever doing an alter system, thanks.

Comment: @cduffin: rather then using `show wal_level` you can use `select name, setting, sourcefile, sourceline from pg_settings where name = 'wal_level';` then you can see *where*  the property was set

Comment: in my docker container th file `postgresql.auto.conf` is in `/var/lib/postgresql/data`